# Treat short swipe as click

Tags: javascript, events, touch, swipe, dom-events

I have a mobile web app, which uses a lot of `click` event handlers on buttons, etc. All of this works fine if the user really "clicks" (i.e. "touchdown-touchup") the button.  However if the user does a short swipe, then the `click` event does not fire. This causes a lot of complaints from my users that the app doesn't register clicks/taps and that other apps work correctly.

Of course, I can get coordinates of the touch in `ontouchstart` and `ontouchend` and compute the distance - but I need to also know whether that distance is under the maximum that the browser would treat as 'click'.  I do *not* want to switch to using touchstart/touchend events instead of click.

I used to use fastclick.js library for handling clicks/taps in the past, but now use native 'click' events with `touch-action: manipulation`.  Is there any way of specify/controlling the maximum movement of the finger on the button that still registers as a 'click'?

**Update** based on comments.  The application is very large and there are hundreds if not thousands of event handler assignments throughout it (the app has been developed over the last 8 years).  Changing all of these is not practical, therefore I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to either set the threshold once globally or solve the problem with a global-like touchstart/touchend handlers.

Comment: since you know the distance and therefore the delta why not just define your own threshold?

Comment: @mad.meesh I think you missed part of my question: _how_ to define this threshold?

Comment: oh ... you didn’t quite say that but in that case you just do `const threshold=some_val` and then check your distance against it and if true then call the click handler

Comment: It's not that simple, because I only need to call the click handler if the threshold is above the standard click threshold, otherwise, the click will happen twice.

Comment: hmm.. then i would define a `cooldown` like `lastClicked` and/or a `bool` such as `hasClicked` that would control your click rate

Comment: That would require modifying all existing click handlers - there are hundreds if not thousands of them.  The full app is in the area of 100,000 lines of javascript code. I was hoping to either have one global place where I could set this threshold in the beginning - or a global touchstart/touchend handlers.

Comment: Do you know the order the events will be seen? does `touchend` come before or after `click` in the case where the distance would be small enough to trigger the click twice?

Comment: @gforce301 I tested it - touchend always comes before click

Comment: Strange enough, I ran recently in a similar issue with some HDPI Android devices. I solved this by implementing a `touchRadius` of 4 pixels in my global gesture handler, using the events `touch`and `release`.

Answer (score 1):

I thought this was an interesting problem so I took a shot at solving it for you. In a way it's somewhat similar to the problem of preventing a `click` event when a `dblclick` happens.

Using a distance threshold for a "short swipe" seems, to me at least, problematic in that the threshold distance might be system dependent. Instead of that I decided to trigger on if the "click" event actually happens. I used `mousedown` as a simulated `touchstart` and `mouseup` as a simulated `touchend`. `mouseup` always happens before `click` so it is similar to `touchend` in that respect.

Normally if you "click" (`mousedown`) on an element and then move your mouse pointer off the element, the `click` event does not happen. This is much like the situation you describe as being a "short swipe". After a certain distance the `click` event just doesn't happen. The code below will send a `click` event for the button even if you mousedown on it, move the pointer off it and then mouseup. I believe that this would solve the problem if you used it for `touchstart` and `touchend` instead

```js
// The pre-exisiting click handler
function handleClick(ev) {
    console.log('button clicked. do work.');
}

document.getElementById('theButton').addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// our global "touch" handlers
var touchHandler = {
    curPending: null,
    curElem: null,

    handleTouch: function handleTouch(ev) {
        switch (ev.type) {
            case 'mousedown':
                // capture the target that the click is being initiated on
                touchHandler.curElem = ev.target;
                
                // add an extra click handler so we know if the click event happens
                ev.target.addEventListener('click', touchHandler.specialClick);
                break;

            case 'mouseup':
                // start a pending click timer in case the click event doesn't happen
                touchHandler.curPending = setTimeout(touchHandler.pendingClick, 1);
                break;
        }
    },

    specialClick: function(ev) {
        // the click event happened 
        // clear our extra handler 
        touchHandler.curElem.removeEventListener('click', touchHandler.specialClick);
        
        // make sure we don't send an extra click event
        clearTimeout(touchHandler.curPending);
    },

    pendingClick: function() {
        // we never heard the click event
        
        // clear our extra handler 
        touchHandler.curElem.removeEventListener('click', touchHandler.specialClick);

        // trigger a click event on the element that started it all
        touchHandler.curElem.click();
    }
};

// using "mousedown" as "touchstart" and "mouseup" as "touchend"
document.addEventListener('mouseup', touchHandler.handleTouch);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', touchHandler.handleTouch);
```

```html
<p>I work when clicked normally but I also work when 
mousedown, drag pointer off me, mouseup</p>
<button id="theButton">Click Me</button>
```